# SOLVED :D New GFCI outlets won't work, but old one works fine!

Tags: gfci

I'm trying to go with nicer, newer outlets throughout my thirty year old house, and with great guidance from the friendly older gentleman at Home Depot, I got a Leviton Tamper Resistant GFCI Outlet with Night Light (the regular light switches and outlets I'm using are the dummy-proof ones).  It got power - verified with a detector, but the test and reset buttons did not work.  So I bought another of the same outlet, thinking the outlet was faulty - same thing happened.  So I bought a third outlet, this time a Leviton Tamper Resistant GFCI with Audible Alarm - same thing happened.  In desperation, I cleaned the many layers of paint off the old GFCI (not tamper resistant, and hence no longer up to code), and it worked no problem - as does the secondary bathroom outlet that it connects to.  Each time I hooked up the wires, from first to fourth install, I copied how it was wired from the old outlet to the next exactly.  I followed the instructions to the letter from the insert.  I really want updated - to code - GFCI's (I have three in the house), but I'm at a total loss!

On a side note, I had to move my guest bath wall fixture over ~4" to be centered over the vanity - I assume the original vanity was smaller.  In YouTubing how to do this, I did learn that my master bath light fixture was installed against code by being mounted directly to a stud, without a box (maybe code changed since the house was built, or maybe the electricians were careless), so I have ordered a 1/2" box to rectify that.  Though unrelated, I am now wondering whether this GFCI issue I'm having and the incorrectly housed lighting fixture are indicative of issues with the electric not having been run properly?

Thank you in advance for any guidance!!!

Comment: Modern GFCIs have a Line side and Load side, marked on the device. The wires going back to your panel (which supply power) should be connected to the Line side - is that how you wired it?

Comment: It happens to the best, show us pictures of wiring

Comment: I think the old GFCI has Line Side and Load Side also marked on the back, and I copied install from that.  I obviously don't know whether the old GFCI is original to the house as we purchased three years ago, but I did look at this in my troubleshooting :(  Since it's now 11pm, and I currently don't have lighting in the bathroom due to moving the fixture over, I can add photos tomorrow!

Comment: Most/many GFCIs ship in a tripped condition, and need to be **Reset** with power applied to the LINE terminals before they will otherwise "work" - is that your issue?

Comment: New GFCI's have a (typically yellow) label covering their 'load' terminals. Did you remove that label and use the load terminals, or did you use the other terminals where were not covered?

Comment: FIXED - thank you so much, everyone!  I made the assumption that the Line would have been at the top of the old outlet, and it was not, that brand puts it at the bottom.  I now have a perfectly working, up to code, GFCI!  Feel pretty dumb to have not noticed that, but this is all new to me, my husband always did this kind of stuff in our last two houses when he was alive.

Comment: @Emma -- post your update as an answer and I'll give you +1 for it :)

Comment: "I followed the instructions to the letter from the insert." - So no, you definitely did not.

Comment: I can't figure out how to update this to a "answer."  And as far as reading the insert, I need new bifocals - I had to take a photo of the old receptacle and zoom in on it to see that Line and Load were swapped - I have widow's brain after unexpectedly losing my husband a year ago :(

Comment: You don't update it to an answer, you " answer your own qquestion"

Comment: Added the details into the Answer via edit and copy-paste.

Comment: Thank you, @keshlam!

Comment: @nobody, I hope you show more grace if one of your loved ones unexpectedly loses their spouse in an accident after 25 years together. It's an honest mistake to assume that all GFCI outlets would have a universal design despite brand, and that the "top line" would be the same from brand to brand. This is literally the first time in my life I'm trying to do electrical, which I think I was clear about, and your unbelievably rude comment in a website meant for learning only shows what a complete a$$ you must be in real life!

Comment: The comment was more blunt than necessary, but it's not an _entirely_ bad point -- when debugging in the future, one of the most useful things to do is go back to first principles and check everything step by step. All too often, it's the assumptions or hasty reading or something of that sort which turns around and bites our ankles.

Answer (score 6):

FIXED - thank you so much, everyone! I made the assumption that the Line would have been at the top of the old outlet, and it was not, that brand puts it at the bottom. I now have a perfectly working, up to code, GFCI! Feel pretty dumb to have not noticed that, but this is all new to me, my husband always did this kind of stuff in our last two houses when he was alive.

Thank you, Jack!